# AppCheck in android flutter app failed in Release mode on real device

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, release, firebase-app-check

I am having issues with read/write to Firestore when AppCheck is activated and when running the release version on real device (not tested on simulator)

The journey...

Flutter app initialize as follow:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);      
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
```

I generate an appbundle for android and publish it.

I collected the SHA256 key of the App signing key and Upload key certificate from Google console
And add it to the Firebase AppCheck configuration.

In release mode, all the calls are rejected. "Permission denied"

In debug mode I am able to make it work when I manually add the debug token to the AppCheck console.

I first suspect a Security rules issues but even with
`allow read, write: if true;`
it does not work.

As soon as I deactivate the AppCheck from the firebase it works.

I also unzipped the app bundle file to double in META-INF what is the SHA256 key used and it is the one I put in the AppCheck Console.

My versions in pubspec is the following:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.6
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+5
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.3
  firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.6
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.6
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.5
  cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.6
```

Flutter version is 3.3.8
in build.gradle the important parts I guess are:

[image]

The resolutionStrategy part was from the thread :
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8501
due to issues after upgrade to 3.3.8

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what can be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603486/flutter-firestore-read-write-not-working-in-release-when-enabling-appcheck

Comment: was a solution found for this since the "duplicate" was deleted